# Find the probability of double drawing

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Two urns contain, respectively, $20$ white and $10$ black balls and $10$ white and $50$ black balls. $5$ balls are transferred from the first urn to the second urn, and then $1$ ball is drawn from the second urn and is found to be white.  What is the probability that this white ball comes form first urn?

I can find the probability of 'the ball drawn from the 2nd urn is found to be white', I also can find the probability of 'the five balls transferred are all white when it is known that we found the ball from the 2nd urn is white'... but this particular Question is very confusing

> How do I find the probability of drawing a white ball from the second urn?

let

$W =$ White, $B= $ Black

$X \equiv$ Event , founding a white ball from 2nd urn.

Following events are considered when transferring the balls from 1st urn to 2nd urn :

$A \equiv $ Event, $(1W,4B)$

$B \equiv $ Event, $(2W,3B)$

$C \equiv $ Event, $(3W,2B)$

$D \equiv $ Event, $(4W,1B)$

$E \equiv $ Event, $(5W,0B)$

$P(X) = P(X|A)P(A)+ P(X|B)P(B)+P(X|C)P(C)+P(X|D)P(D)+P(X|E)P(E)$

Comment: What do you mean by : "and then 1 ball is drawn form the second urn and is found to be white"

Comment: after transferring 5 balls arbitrarily from 1st urn to 2nd urn, one ball is drawn from the 2nd urn and found to be white..

Comment: When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own attempt to solve the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: I tried this problem using Bayes' theorem... but failed to do that.

Comment: I can find the probability of 'the ball drawn from the 2nd urn is found to be white', I also can find the probability of 'the five balls transferred are all white when it is known that we found the ball from the 2nd urn is white'... but this particular Question is very confusing

Comment: Consider cases:  When the five balls are transferred from the first urn to the second, the number of white balls that are transferred can vary from $0$ to $5$.

Comment: The edited question is a big improvement. You might want to edit again to show how you found the probability that the ball drawn from the second urn is white. That would give a clue to other facts you have deduced about the problem, which people could use to give you better hints; it might also be the case that you made an error already, and someone will spot it and help set you on the right track.

Comment: Your method for finding $P(X)$ is correct and will give the right answer if you calculate all the probabilities on the right-hand side correctly. There is an easier method that relies on finding the _expected_ number of white balls in the second urn just before a ball is drawn from the urn, but you have to understand expected values well in order to be sure you can use that method correctly.

Comment: Please do not use all-caps in your question. This is basically the most universal rule on the internet so you should've figured it's not appropriate on maths.SE either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good first step in trying to apply Bayes' theorem is to *write it down*.
There are a few different ways people do this, but the formula could look like this:
$$
P(B \mid A) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)} = \frac{P(A \mid B)\,P(B)}{P(A)}.
$$

In order to apply the theorem, you need $A$ and $B$ in the formula to match two events you can describe in your problem.
Since you want to know the probability that *the ball drawn from the second urn came originally from the first urn,* **given that** *the ball drawn from the second urn is white,* and since $P(B \mid A)$ can be read "probability of $B$ **given** $A$," the obvious way to apply the theorem is to set
\begin{align}
A &= \text{the ball drawn from the second urn is white}, \\
B &= \text{the ball drawn from the second urn came originally from the first urn}.
\end{align}

You say you found $P(A)$ already, so you next might want to try to find
$P(A\cap B)$ or to find $P(B)$ and $P(A \mid B)$.

Comment: Yes, i also do in this way ... but event $A\cap B$ and event $B$ is not cleared to me

Comment: Of all the probabilities you might need, $P(B)$ should be the easiest to find: just before you draw the ball from the second urn, how many balls were in that urn and how many of those came from the first urn? Then you only need $P(A\mid B)$, which also is not hard if you think about what it really means.

Comment: okay before drawing the ball from the 2nd urn there are total 65 balls in the 2nd urn. and 5 of them are from 1st urn

Comment: i think $P(B)= {5 \over 65}$ ... isn't it??

Comment: I get the same answer in the same way.

Comment: now to find $P(A|B)$ we have to consider the $(A|B)$ =  F and $P(F)$ =$  P(F|A1)P(A1)+ P(F|A2)P(A2)+P(F|A3)P(A3)+P(F|A4)P(A4)+P(F|A5)P(A5)$ where F= finding one white,A[i]= finding i white balls at transferring i.e       (i W,(5-i)B) ... isn't it ??

Comment: I wouldn't do separate cases like that. For $P(A\mid B)$ the "given" event $B$ says the single ball you draw at the very end came from the first urn. Consider one of the balls originally in that urn before you do any drawing. Does that ball have a better chance or a worse chance to be in your hand on the last draw, compared to any other ball the first urn?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29610/discussion-between-deep-and-david-k).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Say that the white balls of the first box are in fact blue. So, what is the probability to draw on a blue ball ?

Comment: probability of finding blue ball is 20 /30

Comment: @DEEP If you only draw one ball from the first urn, probability that _that_ ball is blue is then $20/30$. But that tells you little about drawing five balls from the first urn or one ball from the second urn.

Comment: still confused.. :-(